# How to remove duplicate elements in an existing array in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

How do I create a newArray containing only the unique elements present in Array?

Ex: ARRAY contains elements `aa ab bb aa ab cc` at ARRAY[0-5] respectively.

When I print newARRAY, I want only `aa ab bb cc` at newARRAY[0-3] respectively.

I've searched stack overflow for a while now and nothing is solving my problem. I tried to do `newARRAY=$(ARRAY[@] | sort -u | uniq`, but duplicated elements still exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Naive approach

To get the unique elements of `arr` and assuming that no element contains newlines:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort -u
aa
ab
bb
cc
```

#### Better approach

To get a NUL-separated list that works even if there were newlines:

```
$ printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}" | sort -uz
aaabbbcc
```

(This, of course, looks ugly on a terminal because it doesn't display NULs.)

#### Putting it all together

To capture the result in `newArr`:

```
$ newArr=(); while IFS= read -r -d '' x; do newArr+=("$x"); done < <(printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}" | sort -uz)
```

After running the above, we can use `declare` to verify that `newArr` is the array that we want:

```
$ declare -p newArr
declare -a newArr=([0]="aa" [1]="ab" [2]="bb" [3]="cc")
```

For those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines, the above can be rewritten as:

```
newArr=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' x
do
    newArr+=("$x")
done < <(printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}" | sort -uz)
```

#### Additional comment

Don't use all caps for your variable names.  The system and the shell use all caps for their names and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

Comment: I get: syntax error near unexpected token < ... `done < <(printf "%s\0" "${allIps[@]}" | sort -uz)'

Comment: OK working now - I was using sh to fire the script, not bash - thx

Answer (score 5):

You can use an associatve array to keep track of elements you've seen:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=(aa ab bb aa ab cc)

unset dupes # ensure it's empty
declare -A dupes

for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z ${dupes[$i]} ]]; then
        NEWARRAY+=("$i")
    fi
    dupes["$i"]=1
done
unset dupes # optional

printf "[%s]" "${ARRAY[@]}"
echo
printf "[%s]" "${NEWARRAY[@]}"
echo
```